# Fetch rows where first character is not alphanumeric

Tags: mysql, sql, database, regex

I am adding a few new features to a small project i'm working on and one of them is alpha pagination which looks like

> # 0-9 A B C D E ... X Y Z

I can easily fetch items by their first letter using something like

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE name LIKE 'A%' ...
```

Grouping everything that starts with a number and all other characters is a little more difficult, I assume it would have to use MySQLs REGEXP.

Just to be clear, I need help creating two queries which will fetch all rows where

- the first character of a column is numeric
- the first character of a column is not alphanumeric

Answer (score 36, accepted):

First character is numeric:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE name REGEXP '^[0-9]';
```

First character is not alphanumeric:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE name REGEXP '^[^0-9A-Za-z]';
```

(Note that this is distinct from `NOT REGEXP ^[0-9A-Za-z]`, because you seem to *only* want to match when there *is* in fact a first character.)

You can probably substitute `[^[:alnum:]]` for `[^0-9A-Za-z]`, but I haven't tested it. You can *certainly* substitute `[[:digit:]]` for `[0-9]`, but it's longer. :-)

Also see the [MySQL REGEXP Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).